# With Mercurial, is it possible to have default branch in one shell, and another branch, "bugfix", in another shell?

Tags: mercurial

Because it seems like when

```
hg up default
```

or

```
hg up bugfix
```

is used in one Bash shell, then the other shell also changes to that branch automatically if an `hg branch` is used to show which branch it is.  (so I think if it is a
Ruby on Rails server running, all of a sudden, the code will change to the other branch)

If using two separate clones, it can be done... as if there are two branches... but can be done using the branch feature of hg?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use two separate clones.

Think about it. You're working on two different versions of a file. They differ in content. You have to change the file to reflect one of the two branches. How can a single file have two different contents at the same time (your two-shell idea)?

A different analogy: a shell is a window. The file is an object in the room. Even if you have two windows looking into the same room, you can't have the one object in the room be two different things at the same time. To do that, make an identical room next door, modify the object, and have the second window attached to the cloned room.

Comment: that's true... initially I was thinking `hg up <branch_name>` can add a layer of abstraction to the OS file system... but obviously it is merely changing files.

Answer (score 1):

The different shells seem to be working on the same repository directory.  This won't work since the directory is where the update happens and not the shell.

So you really need two repository directories i.e. clones in order to do this.

If these directories are on the same filesystem this won't cost much time or space since Mercurial optimizes this case by using hard links.

At least if you are on a operating system supporting hard links.

Answer (score 1):

If by "shell" you mean two command shells open to the same directory, then yes, they both change because they are working with the same working directory.

One working directory can only ever be at one place in the repository history.

To work with two different branches or changesets in the project at the same time, make a second clone from the first, and then you can manipulate each independently.